# How do I configure Vulkan to use my AMD graphics card instead of Intel?

Tags: graphics, amd-graphics, vulkan, switchable-graphics

I installed Vulkan but vulkaninfo tells me that it's using the Intel integrated graphics rather than my AMD (it has switchable graphics):

```
VK_LAYER_LUNARG_standard_validation (LunarG Standard Validation Layer) Vulkan version 1.0.131, layer version 1:
    Layer Extensions: count = 0
    Devices: count = 1
            GPU id  : 0 (Intel(R) HD Graphics 4400 (HSW GT2))
            Layer-Device Extensions: count = 0
```

How can I change this? I tried running it with DRI_PRIME=1 but it says the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For my Radeon HD 8670M the radeon driver was enabled by default, which does not support vulkan. The amdgpu driver does though, which is why my solution was to switch to amdgpu:

1. Check if amdgpu is supported

   `sudo lspci -k`

- If it isn't please don't keep following these instructions.

2. `sudo nano /etc/default/grub`

In the line that reads `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT`, add:
`radeon.cik_support=0 amdgpu.cik_support=1 radeon.si_support=0 amdgpu.si_support=1`

3. `sudo nano /etc/modprobe.d/amdgpu.conf`
   Copy the following into the file and save it:

   ```
   options amdgpu si_support=1
   options amdgpu cik_support=1
   ```
4. `sudo nano /etc/modprobe.d/radeon.conf`
   Copy the following into the file and save it:

   ```
   options radeon si_support=0
   options radeon cik_support=0
   ```
5. `sudo update-grub`
6. Reboot and you should be running the amdgpu driver now!

Shout out to libre m on YouTube who led me to this solution:    https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Mr_UFL5ZeKQ